# how to set a name to newly generated keys at relay_chain & parachain_template for v0.9.28

Tags: polkadot, parachain, account

I was looking for an option to set a name for keys in both relay_chain & parachain_template

For that, I was trying to generate new keys from relay_chain & parachain_template of v0.9.28

where I can able to generate new keys at the relay_chain template in v0.9.28
with the following command.
`/target/release/Polkadot key generate --scheme Sr25519 --password-interactive`

In parachain_template ie., v0.9.28, I can't able generate new keys even if I specify the correct path command
`/target/release/parachain-template-node key generate --scheme Sr25519 --password-interactive`
why does this happen?

kindly can anyone let me know how to solve this query.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if you have configured it for your CLI.

Example: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/58d3bc67b9595d0a26f5abba88fe4941a6e75b4a/bin/node/cli/src/cli.rs#L64-L66

For Polkadot, yes.

For Parachain-Template, nope.

---

But it is simply just a CLI tool. You could extend your CLI with it or you could use the subkey directly. They are the same usage.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/bin/utils/subkey